# Zabbix & external monitoring systems

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I need to make freinds zabbix & other monitoring system.

My company uses Zabbix for monitoring. Our partner plans to use other system.
We need to exchange monitoring datas.

I'm interested in coopereation with the next systems: BMC Patrol, MS SCOM, NetCool, Portal.

What is the best way to integrate it?
Maybe via SNMP?

Comment: why move from zabbix?

Comment: I'm not moving to other system. It needs to interaction with partners: they don't use zabbix

Answer (score 0):

Replicate hosts and metrics into your Zabbix (use [Zabbix trapper item type](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/trapper) and setup also Allowed hosts value) and then just use some suitable zabbix-sender implementation and push data into Zabbix.

IMO it's terrible idea, because latency, syncing, ... Do you really need data (item values) or do you need only visualize data from different datasources in one graph?

Comment: There is a data we need. What you can offer if use only visual information?

Comment: Grafana for visual information - but you need to write your own datasources for BMC Patrol, MS SCOM, NetCool, Portal, ... (or at least SQL queries for SQL datasource)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding BMC Patrol you can use History Loader/Propagator KM to export the monitoring data:

https://docs.bmc.com/docs/display/public/unixlinux912/PATROL+KM+for+History+Loader

or you can use the 'dump_hist' command to dump the history data from the agents:

https://docs.bmc.com/docs/display/pia9600/dump_hist+uility

Regarding Netcool events, you could get the information using different approaches, for example, depending on the version, you could get the events from the HTTP interface, as described below:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSNFET_9.2.0/com.ibm.netcool_OMNIbus.doc_7.4.0/omnibus/wip/api/reference/omn_api_http_httpinterface.html

Or perhaps you could create a flat file gateway to read the events and write them on a file:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSHTQ/omnibus/gateways/flatfilegw/wip/concept/flatfilegw_intro.html